slow simulation with GIS
I want to create a population of clients to be served in random points on a map using GIS.
I divided my map in towns which really exist.
I have a linked hash map which links a town with his map.
I create an event with a variable rate between 3 and 15 per hour.
The event chooses a town through a custom distribution and then places the client in a random point inside the town.
I have a fleet of  32 trucks to serve my clients and the area of my map is 5000 squared km.
After the creation of the client I send the nearest truck to the client to serve him and then the truck return in his base.
The simulation seems to run well but is very slow, even in virtual mode. How can I improve the speed of simulation?

Two reasons:

Every new route searched goes to the web-server and therefore takes some time you cannot reduce. However, AnyLogic caches that, so the delay only happens the first time

Your model logic. You can only figure out where the delay is via profiling. AL 8.9 has a build-in tool but also google "profiling for AnyLogic" for some more tips



My simulation seems to have the opposite problem: at the beginning go fast (2 days/sec) and after 10 days go very slow (5-10 minutes/sec)

Is it always after 10 days? Then it is issue 2 above
